# Использование фразы в стихотворении с семантической точки зрения

Tags: фразеология, семантика

Можно ли использовать фразу в стихотворении "тобой история верна" с семантической точки зрения?

Тобой история верна
И память след хранит об этом.       Твоя судьба предрешена –
Держава с брезжащим рассветом!

Answer (score 1):

Россия – Вера для меня,

Твоя судьба неповторима.

Спаси из пламени огня

Надежду в сумраке незримом...

**Тобой история верна**

И память след хранит об этом.

Твоя судьба предрешена –

Держава с **брезжУщим** рассветом!

Комментарий:

В словаре для слова «верный» нет управления беспредложным  Т.п. Поэтому  это **авторский грамматический окказионализм.**

Скорее всего,  ***тобой верна*** – это ***тобой подтверждена.***

Вероятно, автор говорит о том, что ход истории имеет определенные объективные законы,  причем Россия  соответствовала этим законам  в прошлом и будет соответствовать им в дальнейшем. О том, что нашу страну ожидает неминуемый рассвет и позитивное будущее.

Для справок:

1. ВЕРНЫЙ,  1. Соответствующий истине, действительности, обстановке; правильный, точный.  2. Не вызывающий сомнения в своей надёжности; несомненный, очевидный.  **3. (кому-чему).** Такой, который не предаст, не подведёт кого-л., не изменит кому-л.; преданный, надёжный.  4. Неизбежный, неминуемый.
2. Грамматические (морфологические) окказионализмы представляют собой образования, в которых, с точки зрения узуса, в конфликте находятся лексическая семантика и грамматическая форма.
3. Вопрос № 261161
   Здравствуйте!
   Почему "брезжить" - глагол 2го спряжения, а рассвет все-же "брезжУЩий"?
   Ответ справочной службы русского языка

Брезжущий – исключение, написание этого слова следует запомнить.

Comment: Спасибо за раскрытие смысла и исправление орфографической ошибки!

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте задать вопрос: кем (или чем) *верна* история? Возможно, и вам тоже он покажется странным и непонятным, в отличие от вопроса "чем она хороша (кем полна и т. п.)?". История (как летопись и т. п.) либо просто верна, либо лжива в той или иной степени - потому-то и потому-то или в том-то, а не "тем"-то.

Но вполне возможен предложный вариант: "***с** тобой история верна*" - смысл будет таков, что *история, в которой есть (упомянут) персонаж, к которому обращаются*, верна в смысле полноты (с его присутствием в истории; без упоминания персонажа она как бы искажена) - если таким был желаемый смысл.

Comment: Мне показалось маловероятным, чтобы гипотетическому бойфренду светила держава (или скипетр), но и в этом случае с грамматикой было бы то же.

Comment: Я что-то совсем не то увидел по невнимательности. Лучше удалю свой предыдущий комментарий.

Comment: Благодарю за подробный ответ!